# html5 player controls in safari is too long

Tags: jquery, css, html, video-player

View here:

[image]

For some reason my html5 player in safari looks a bit longer than the width of the movie. I cant's seem to control it with `style="width: whatever"`.

```
<video id="vid1" width="960" height="540" 
       onclick="this.paused?this.play():this.pause();" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust dynamically the width of your video container to the width of your loaded video. You can use the videoWidth property for this.

```
$('#vid1').on('loadedmetadata', function(){
    var videoW = $(this)[0].videoWidth;
    $(this).css('width', videoW);
});
```

Edit:

In your picture it seems that video css are using a big border. Beware with css `box-sizing` property. Do a test and remove borders or use `box-sizing: border-box;` style in your video element.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I had this in my css:

```
#vid1::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    width: calc(100%+30px); /* Adjust as needed */
}
```